# Quick way to get GIT, CVS, SVN or Bugzilla data

Tags: svn, git, cvs, bugzilla

I need to find all defect for data such as id number, severity and lines of code in the fix for a specific module in eclipse.

Is there a quick way I can do this using CVS, GIT, SVN or Bugzilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter git log output:

```
git log PATH/IN/REPO
```

or for a specific file:

```
git log PATH/IN/REPO/SOURCE.FILE
```

to see actual line changes, use `-p`:

```
git log -p PATH
```